# php: Form to change password and insert current password

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I'm making a form at which if user wants to change their password, i made a code that could change password from database but I want to implement some function before changing password, current password would be asked so that they can change their password, But how to do it?

code to update database:
**strong text**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    mysqli_query($con,"update admin set password=SHA1( CONCAT('Rajendra')) WHERE id='$id'");
}
echo "<h2>Your password is successfully changed..</h2>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is a code for form:

```
<?php
include('lock.php');
?>

<form method="post" action="db_change_password.php">

            <label><strong>Current password: </strong></label>
            <input type="password" name="current_password" value="password"><br><br>
            <label><strong>New password: </strong></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="password"><br><br>
            <label><strong>Confirm password: </strong></label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" value="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

            <label><p><strong><br>NOTE: </strong>After changing password, you have to put your new password during login time.</p></label>
        </form>
```

**EDITING**

login script:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form
    $myemail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email='$myemail' AND password='".sha1($mypassword)."'";

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $active=$row['active'];
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myemail and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1)
    {
        $_SESSION["myemail"];
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$myemail;

        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: invalid_login_form.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When the user is logged in create a `$_SESSION` where the password is stored.

Comment: I have already created this...

Comment: Where I can't see it.

Comment: okay w8, i'm editing it, actually i'm making a small project for social networking site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would however make a session with the user_id

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['email']."'");

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(sha1($_POST['current_password']) == $row['password'])
    {
       $id=$row['id'];
       mysqli_query($con,"update admin set password=SHA1( CONCAT('Rajendra')) WHERE id='$id'");
     } else {
       echo "incorrect password";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before updating the password, you can add a check to test the current password.

Comment: And will you please elaborate me, how to do it?

Comment: Write a select query to check for the user and the current password. If query is true, you can go ahead and change the password otherwise throw an error that current password is invalid.